# Bootstrap Grid System Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I can't uderstand just one simple detail.
I'm just a newbie in Bootstrap, so need help.

How can i create the grid system at the Bootstrap like this without fixed height of cols?

[image]

Web example is [here](http://pieoneers.com/work).

Answer (score 0):

You can nest grid components within grid components like in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eRVTssyDZuf2Tr5hTbg4?p=preview)

```
 <div class="container">
  <!---Main seperation 4 cols-->
  <div class="col-sm-4">

    <div class=col-sm-12>
      <img src="//placehold.it/150x300">
    </div>
    </div>

  <!---Main seperation 8 cols-->
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-3 "><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 "><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
    </div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px"> 
      <div class="col-sm-3 "><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 "><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
    </div>
       <div class="row" > 
      <div class="col-sm-3 "><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 "><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1"><img src="//placehold.it/150x100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```